# Selenium "get elements inside another element" in nodejs

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to click in the third input box but I can't use a xpath [3] because it's isolated by divs. How can I get the third "div class price filter" and then get the input?

```
<div class="search-prices">
    <div class="search-price-header">
        <h1>Bid Price:</h1>
        <button class="flat camel-case disabled" disabled="">Clear</button>
    </div>
    <div class="price-filter">
        <div class="info"><span class="label">Min:</span></div>
        <div class="ut-numeric-input-spinner-control">
            <button class="btn-standard decrement-value disabled" disabled=""></button>
                <input type="tel" class="numericInput" placeholder="Any">
                <button class="btn-standard increment-value"></button></div>
    </div>
    <div class="price-filter">
        <div class="info"><span class="label">Max:</span></div>
        <div class="ut-numeric-input-spinner-control">
            <button class="btn-standard decrement-value disabled" disabled=""></button>
                <input type="tel" class="numericInput" placeholder="Any">
            <button class="btn-standard increment-value"></button></div>
    </div>
    <div class="search-price-header">
        <h1>Buy Now Price:</h1><button class="flat camel-case disabled" disabled="">Clear</button>
    </div>
    <div class="price-filter"></div>
        <div class="info"><span class="label">Min:</span></div>
        <div class="ut-numeric-input-spinner-control">
            <button class="btn-standard decrement-value disabled"disabled=""></button>
                <input type="tel" class="numericInput" placeholder="Any">
            <button class="btn-standard increment-value"></button></div>
    </div>
    <div class="price-filter">
        <div class="info"><span class="label">Max:</span></div>
        <div class="ut-numeric-input-spinner-control">
            <button class="btn-standard decrement-value disabled"disabled=""></button>
                <input type="tel" class="numericInput" placeholder="Any">
            <button class="btn-standard increment-value"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried something like

```
  var priceFilter = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='price-filter'][3]"));   
  var numericInput = priceFilter.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='numericInput']"))
  numericInput.click();
```

But my click always happens in the first input, any idea why?

Comment: There's an extra </div> in there somehow, that's not really what the dom looks like.

Comment: sorry? what it's meaning?

Comment: Where does that html come from? The source or the inspector panel?

Comment: @MatheusCampos I just added my answer. Can you give a try?

Comment: That comes from inspector..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xpath that works for me is:

```
//div[@class='price-filter'][3]//input[@class='numericInput']
```

thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath: `(//div[@class='price-filter']//input)[3]`

Comment: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//div[@class='price-filter']//input)[3]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: You less `(` in front xpath

Comment: It should `(//div[@class='price-filter']//input)[3]`, please try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know whether this works or not.

```
var numericInput =priceFilter.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@class='numericInput'])[3]"))

numericInput.click();
```